# Vue-Router redirection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a simple oauth2 authentification workflow.
User provides with credentials -> authorization server gives authorization with callback uri **auth/login/callback** with param **code**.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HomePage from './../components/HomePage.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
mode: 'history',
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
            // check for authentication
            // if from "/" then go to login process else serve page
            if (from.fullPath == "/") {
            // login 
                next('/auth/login')
            }

            if (from.fullPath == "/auth/login/callback") {
                next()
            }
            // other case no access to resource
            next(false)

        },
        component: HomePage,
    },
    {
        path: "/auth/login/callback",
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
            // get authorization code from callback identity provider
            fetch("/api/GetToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + to.query.code)
                .then(async response => {
                    const data = await response.json()
                    // check for error response
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        const error = (data & data.message) || response.status;
                        return Promise.reject(error)
                    } else {
                        to.params.token = data
                        next("/")
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error("Error : ", error)
                    next(false)
                })

        },
        component: HomePage,

    }
]
})
```

For some reason this snippet doesn't work. The goal is to redirect not logged in user to /auth/login and to serve the HomePage with props token in case of successful login.

The get token part works fine but then when happens the next("/") the route (path="/") doesn't recognize the origin of the request. from.path = "/" and to.path = "/".

Can you pls help on that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add name for route with "/" path then use next() method like this:

```
next({ name: name_of_/_path })
```

Not sure it might work but you can give a shot.

Comment: no unfortunately it doesn't work. I have to.name = name_of_/_path but from.name = null...